Derivative of Convolution with Respect to Input Image
Given a discrete convolution operation for image processing like this:
$$
H(x, y) = \sum_{i=-a}^{a} \sum_{j=-b}^{b} K(i, j) \cdot I(x - i, y - j)
$$
It is common for CNNs to take the derivative with respect to the kernel.
However, I would like the derivative with respect to the input pixels:
$$\frac{\partial H(x, y)}{\partial I(p, q)}$$
Where p,q is one specific point of the input image.
How does this work? I believe the derivative with respect to one pixel is the value of the kernel at the x,y location

What’s your confusion?

I'm not sure how to derive the answer.

and additionally, I'm not sure how to interpret the overall answer (the derivative of the output image with respect to the input image.) is this a jacobian

Given $(x, y)$ there exists at most one point $(i,j)$ such that $-a\leq i\leq a$, $-b\leq j \leq b$ and
$$
(x-i, y-j) = (p, q),
$$
that is $i = x-p, j = y-q$. In such case your derivative is $K(i, j) = K(x-p,y-q)$. If such point does not exist, derivative is $0$. A point exists iff $-a\leq x-p\leq a$ and $-b\leq y-q\leq b$.
